# How could I get a neat Chessboard layout? react DnD and javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I decided to follow the next tutorial of React DnD: 
http://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/tutorial

So far, I've followed to the letter the process, the code successfully compiled and ran however, I'm not getting the expected results. I wonder if you could help me to find a way to work this out?

[image]

It seems like only the square where the knight positioned displays and not the complete 64 squares chessboard.

To be honest, I'm also learning React currently. I thought it was a problem with the browser, but I got the same results with Chrome and Mozilla.

This is the code for the Board

```
import React from 'react'
import Square from './Square'
import Knight from './Knight'

function renderSquare(i, [knightX, knightY]) {
  const x = i % 8
  const y = Math.floor(i / 8)
  const isKnightHere = x === knightX && y === knightY
  const black = (x + y) % 2 === 1
  const piece = isKnightHere ? <Knight /> : null

  return (
    <div key={i} style={{ width: '12.5%', height: '12.5%' }}>
      <Square black={black}>{piece}</Square>
    </div>
  )
}

export default function Board({ knightPosition }) {
  const squares = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    squares.push(renderSquare(i, knightPosition))
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      }}
    >
      {squares}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This is how my index.js looks like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Knight from "./Knight";
import Square from './Square';
import Board from './Board'

ReactDOM.render(<Knight />, document.getElementById('root'));
ReactDOM.render(
    <Square black>
      <Knight/>
    </Square>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Board knightPosition={[7, 4]} />,
  document.getElementById('root'),
)
```

Square.js

```
import React from 'react'

  export default function Square({ black, children }) {
    const fill = black ? 'black' : 'white'
    const stroke = black ? 'white' : 'black'

    return (
      <div
        style={{
          backgroundColor: fill,
          color: stroke,
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Your renderer in the code is also displaying only the knight and tile that the knight is on. Compare that to the tutorial which displays all the board. IDK, try displaying the board first and then go for the knight. Plus, you haven't added code from kight.js and board.js

Answer (score 0):

The Tutorial never explicitly sets boundaries for the board.

In index.js add a style attribute to the div wrapping the Board state.

```
observe((knightPosition) =>
  ReactDOM.render(
    <div style={{ width: "500px", height: "500px" }}>
      {" "}
      <Board rookPosition={knightPosition} />
    </div>,
    root
  )
);
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. Is your problem that the Board component extends outside the containing div?  What is "The Tutorial"?